# Export Map Style from Google Maps Platform

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-platform

Google have decided to replace their [Map Style tool](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) with the [Cloud-base Maps Styling](https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/client-styles).

The new *Beta* tool allows you to import JSON map styling, but it provides no way of exporting a map style created with the Beta tool.

A colleague of mine has created a custom Map Style, but now we need to copy it into another project, but there appears no way to do this. We can duplicate the style, but only into the same project.

Is there any way around this, eg. a GCP console command.

I've tried inspecting the network traffic to see if I can grab the config, but it's in a completely different format that can't be exported.

**Edit**: It may appear I've done no research on this question, but the fact is that because it's referring to a Beta GCP tool, there is very little information available on its use other than:

- [A blog post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/introducing-new-maps-customization-features)
- A sidebar which concentrates on the publishing side
- All the Maps API docs refer to using a Map ID, which isn't the problem here.

**Another Edit**:I've created an [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/234571049), in case anyone is interested...

Comment: What does the official documentation say about that?

Comment: Unfortunately, while there is documentation regarding the concept of Map Styles, Map IDs, etc. There is just a blog post, and sidebar on how to use the new Beta tool, which concentrates more on the saving and publishing of maps.

Comment: The feature is in Beta, as you know already, so it's possible that not every functionality is yet available and/or properly documented. I could not find any export option either. I'd suggest you browse their [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:188853) for an existing bug or feature request and if you can't find any, open a new one.

Comment: FYI, documentation is available [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/cloud-customization/overview). It might be possible that you could do something (like exporting or copying the maps style to another project) with [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell) but I have not explored the possibilities yet.

Comment: Thanks. I'll add an issue to the Maps Platform component.
I've left feedback in the Console as that's the best place I could find. Like you say, no mention is in the Walkthrough, so it's safe to assume an export feature doesn't exist.
At the very least others who encounter this issue (or similar) will see they're not the only ones...

Comment: It shouldn't be too difficult to extract `MapStyleOptions` as JSON from a styled map object.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I had thought the same, however I've watched the traffic from both the GCP console and the JS API, and the requested data is nothing like the JSON accepted by the new Map Editor. The JS API does however return a string that appears to contain an encoded version - https://pastebin.com/EhxusMN7 - but it doesn't look that simple.

Comment: any updates on this - is it possible to export the new created style or share it ?

Comment: @Aristidios As of today, not that I can see.

Comment: Any updates? how can they release something where only half of the features work? At least let the old version work parallel.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a workaround to get the JSON from the style editor.

- Go to the Google Maps dashboard [map style editor](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/google/maps-apis/studio/styles)
- Choose one of their eaxmple styles, or import your current map style JSON.dev
- Make any changes you need.
- Open the browser dev tools for that window (F12)
- Switch to the Network tab, and select "Fetch/XHR" (for Chrome - other browsers are similar)
- You might find the next step easier if you clear the tab (with the  button)
- Click "Save"/"Save and publish" on the map style editor page.
- Look for a POST request in the dev tools network tab to a URL like this:
  `https://cloudconsole-pa.clients6.google.com/v3/entityServices/MapsMapsstylingEntityService/schemas/MAPS_MAPSSTYLING_ENTITY_SERVICE_GQL_TRANSPORT`, and click on it.
- Copy the request payload from the Response tab, and paste it into a text editor.

[image: POST response payload]

- In this JSON, look for the "rules" property and copy its value out.

**This is the map style JSON that you need to style your map.**

I had to do a little cleanup. For example I had to find and replace the escaped quote characters (ie. `\"` to `"`).

Plus the map style rules didn't look exactly the same in my app as they did in the editor.  I'm not sure why. Perhaps the editor has some default rules that are not in the submitted JSON.  So you might need to do a little bit of style tweaking.

However, in my case, I just needed a couple of rules from this JSON to finish the styling of my map.  There were a couple of features I couldn't seem to get working properly.  And being able to copy the relevant rules from the editor JSON solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the idea [Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau)!  I can suggest an improvement to your process, using the browser dev tools console to help with parsing.  I've copied your first 8 steps for ease of the next person.  This process seemed to work for me (was able to import the style to another project, and it seems to have the desired styling).  Note I am also using Chrome (other browser's dev tools may be different).

- Go to the Google Maps dashboard [map style editor](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/google/maps-apis/studio/styles)
- Choose one of their example styles, or import your current map style JSON.dev
- Make any changes you need.
- Open the browser dev tools for that window (cmd-shift-J on Chrome on Mac)
- Switch to the Network tab, and select "Fetch/XHR" (for Chrome - other browsers are similar)
- You might find the next step easier if you clear the tab (with the  button)
- Click "Save"/"Save and publish" on the map style editor page.
- Look for a POST request in the dev tools network tab to this URL: `https://cloudconsole-pa.clients6.google.com/v3/entityServices/MapsMapsstylingEntityService/schemas/MAPS_MAPSSTYLING_ENTITY_SERVICE_GQL_TRANSPORT`
- *NOTE from here onward this is where my process differs from* [Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau)
- Click the Payload tab
- Expand "Request Payload" one level (if not already expanded)
- Right-click on the JSON content (starts with "{requestContext:")
- Choose "Copy value"
- In the Console window of dev tools, begin an assignment statement (but do NOT yet hit return):

  - origRequest =
- Paste the value you copied directly on to that assignment statement
- Add a semi-colon ; and hit return.  Now the request payload is in a valid JavaScript variable that you can utilize like any other.
- To get the "rules" field (as described by @paul-lebeau), *without* the need to manipulate any escaped quotes, enter this command in the console window:
- `copy(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(origRequest.variables.clientStyle.draftJsonEncodedStyleSheet).rules,0,2))`

  - or `publishedJsonEncodedStyleSheet` if you clicked publish above

The rules JSON is now in your paste buffer.  You can paste it into the editor of your choice if you want to adjust it further, or you can paste it directly into the "Import JSON" text area of the Google Maps Style editor (which in my case worked without need of any adjustment).

Also note that adjustments can be made in that console window too, if you prefer to work with the parsed JSON object.  To do that, create the origRequest object as described above, then:

- `rules = JSON.parse(origRequest.variables.clientStyle.draftJsonEncodedStyleSheet).rules;`
- Manipulate the "rules" javascript object as desired, then:
- `copy(JSON.stringify(rules,0,2))`

Comment: Nice and clean. Why in the world don't they just have an export button!!?